# Simple Angular2 Reactive Form control enable state change

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming, observable

I have a form with `first_name` and `last_name` fields.

When both of these fields have a value entered, I wish to **enable** another formControl in the same form.

I know I can subscribe to the changes like this:

```
  createForm() {
    this.myForm = new FormGroup({
      first_name: this.first_name,
      last_name: this.last_name,
      email: this.email,
      mobile: this.mobile,
      salutation: this.salutation
    });
    this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(data => console.log('form changes', (!data.first_name == !data.last_name)));
  }
```

which logs to the console and shows 'true' when both values are set.

You can see from [this thread](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11271) on angular github that we cannot/should not set that to a property and bind `[disabled]=<booleanProperty>` (and the core team seem to still be working on this issue).

So how do I use the result from my valueChanges stream above to actually set the other control to an enabled state?

In the OnInit it is disabled as per the guides:

```
this.salutation = new FormControl({value:'', disabled: true}, Validators.required);
```

**UPDATE**

Sorry I forgot to mention that I already tried this, in the OnInit:

```
this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
  if (!data.first_name == !data.last_name) {
    this.salutation.enable();
  };
})
```

That does not work, it throws console error: `Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stack size exceeded was the clue to solving this. Since the stream is 'continuous' my code kept setting the control to enabled - but of course, it only needs to be enabled once.

So adding a check solved the problem, and now it works:

```
this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
  if (!data.first_name == !data.last_name && this.myForm.controls['salutation'].disabled) {
    this.myForm.controls['salutation'].enable();
  };
})
```

Further info [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13570)

Answer (score 0):

In the subscribe function, do something like

```
this.myForm.controls["controlToEnable"].enable();
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that. It doesn't work and also throws error max stack size exceeded. I'll add to the question to illustrate, maybe my code is wrong.